# How to keep the unchanged branch files after merging branches in gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-api

I want to something to know , If I merge the branch , conflicts happens, If I cleared that, the destination will change right!!! but I want unmerged files also like ( for eg: merge request from dev(source branch) to stage(destination)--->conflicts ----->cleared----->any how the destination branch will change but I want the changed branch (changed files) as well unchanged branch files like (before merging )for eg: merge dev to stage---->I want dev files & dev merged to stage files and also stage files (unmerged file also).The problem was , If the stage files changed after merging , for future deployment I want the unmerged stage deployment files. at the time I suffer .Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I want dev files & dev merged to stage files and also stage files (unmerged file also)

You have them. No commit in Git is ever lost, and every commit contains all the files, so you have every file in every state it was ever in during any commit.

Comment: No I want three branch files ( source , merged(source to destination) and unmerged(destination before merging) @matt

Comment: @CyrilI: as Matt said, they're all in there, in the commits. Every commit stores every file permanently; once committed, that copy of the file is in that commit forever, and can never change. You simply tell Git "show me the committed copy of the file" and it does so. For instance, `git show <hash>:<path>`.

Comment: in GitLab ,where I've to tell? "You simply tell Git "show me the committed copy of the file" and it does so" @torek

Comment: Like I said, `git show <hash>:<path>` at the command line. Find the hash of the commit that contains the version of the file you want. Replace `<hash>` with the hash ID and `<path>` with the path. (There are other shorter ways, but learn this one first.)

Comment: Ok fine thank you